# Open access/view dbf file

Tags: ms-access, oledb

I am new to C#, and I want to begin working with dbf files.  I’ve found the small script below that should open Access to the dbf file “kategori”, that I want to view and later modify. The file is located in the debug directory and is named “kategori.dbf”. 
Code:

```
namespace SQLApplikation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connetionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\au159403\Google Drive\C#\SQLApplikation\SQLApplikation\bin\Debug\; Extended Properties = dBASE IV;Initial Catalog=kategori;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I receive the error after the line `cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);`

> “System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'provider'.'”

When I hit the key assigned in form.  I believe this is linked to how I define the source but since I am at the Rookie stage, I would appreciate if anyone could guide me to a solution.
Kind Regards H

Answer (score 0):

You are using the sqlprovider.

You have to use the oleDB provider.
(anytime you see a connection string with "provider=" means oleDB.

eg:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
               "Data Source=c:\fax;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;"
    Dim daRead As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from FAXBOOK", strCon)
    daRead.Fill(rstData)
    With rstData
        If .Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No data found")
        Else
            MsgBox("Rows of data found = " & .Rows.Count & vbCrLf &
                   "First row of data: FAXNAME  = " & .Rows(0).Item("FAXNAME") & vbCrLf &
                   "Pk ID (first row) = " & .Rows(0).Item("ID"))
        End If
    End With
```

Note that I did not create a connection object, since the data adapter takes a connection object, or a connection string.

HOWEVER:
Because you are using a file based system, then often the system gets a little more "pickey" about closing the file, and cleaning up things. So, I would suggest this example (and for learning - I do create a connection object).

I don't know what the equivalent "using" statement is in C#, but it high recommended since it cleans up after itself. (closes the windows file handles).

```
    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using MyCon As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.DbaseJETole)
        Dim daRead As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from FAXBOOK", MyCon)
        daRead.Fill(rstData)
        With rstData
            If .Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("No data found")
            Else
                MsgBox("Rows of data found = " & .Rows.Count & vbCrLf &
                   "First row of data: HotelName = " & .Rows(0).Item("FAXNAME") & vbCrLf &
                   "Pk ID (first row) = " & .Rows(0).Item("ID"))
            End If
        End With
    End Using
```

In above, I used a my.settings, but the string is same as first example. Note the use of JUST a path name - the so called free form d-base tables are determined by the file name of the .dbf file in that folder (so table name = FILENAME.DBF of file in that folder).

So you have 3 typical providers in .net

```
sqlProvider      - for use with sql server
oleDBProvider    - for use with any oleDB driver you have installed
ODBCProvider     - for use with any ODBC driver you have istalled.
```

They all work quite much the same (connection objects, datareader, and dataAdaptor).
However,to use JET translation to dbaseIII etc.? You can't hit JET with ODBC to do this translate to dBaseIII, but you have to use oleDB.

Also, keep in mind that win 7 to win 10 usually WILL have a native dbase ODBC driver installed. So you could use ODBC and use this:

```
    Imports System.Data.Odbc

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim strCon As String = "Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};dbq=C:\FAX;defaultdir=C:\FAX;fil=dBase 5.0"
    Dim myCon As New OdbcConnection(strCon)
    Dim daRead As New OdbcDataAdapter("select * from FAXBOOK", myCon)
    daRead.Fill(rstData)
```

I am not 100% sure, but I  do think that dbase drivers are a default in windows. But, you have to use ODBC as per above, as I don't think by default a oleDB provider is installed for dBase formats. (so you can do what you are doing, and use JET).

So, to build your connection, your string looks good - but oleDB providers are required

```
DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

string strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=c:\fax;Extended 
    Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
OleDbDataAdapter daRead = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from FAXBOOK", strCon);
daRead.Fill(rstData);
```